# recurrent job runs only once

Tags: sql-server-2008, job-scheduling

I have a SQL job schedule to run daily. There are 8 jobs running with the same schedule. 6 jobs run properly. The remaining two run only once when i start the jobs manually, subsequent recurring runs never happen. There is no information about these two in job history.

It looks like the scheduler does not invoke the mentioned two jobs at all.

Comment: When you open the job in the agent. On the first page 'General' there is a checkbox 'Enable' is it checked?

Comment: Have the two jobs been actually assigned schedules (on the *Schedules* page of the *Properties* dialog)? It is possible to create a job without a schedule attached to it.

Comment: The jobs are enabled, schedule is assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: set the schedule to run once in 24 hours, added start time and end times with 30 minutes of interval.